# how to update multiple value in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have input data that I will fill with different values, I do multiple updates

but I have an error which is:

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' UPDATE `service` SET
>   `charges_order` = WHERE array `id_service` = '1'

how to overcome this?

[example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWEUb.png)

View

```php
<?php $no = 1; foreach ($invoice as $m) { ?>
<tbody id="tbody">
        <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>backend/report/update/<?php echo $m->id_service; ?>">
            <tr class="deleted">
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="charges_order[]" value="<?php echo $m->charges_order;?>"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
</tbody>
    <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-blue btns-flat margin">Simpan</button>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Controller

```
public function update($id_service)
{
    foreach ($this->input->post('charges_order') as $data) {
        $data = array(
            'charges_order' => $this->input->post('charges_order')
        );
        // echo '<pre>', print_r($data);
        $this->M_report->update($id_service, $data);
        redirect('backend/report');
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function update($id_service, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id_service', $id_service);
    $this->db->update('service', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller to this-

```
public function update($id_service){  
    $charges_order = json_encode($this->input->post('charges_order'));

    $data = array(
                'charges_order' => $charges_order
            );
    $this->M_report->update($id_service, $data);       
    redirect('backend/report');
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Does this send all the data to the database ? (Previous values are replaced by new values, Database always have last element of an array )

Comment: @Dum Hey, I have updated the code, see if that works for you. :)

Comment: I think so :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You are in a loop. You must use the variable.

```
$data = array(
    'charges_order' => $data
);
```

Comment: only one data has changed @Akintunde-Rotimi

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array into a string and then update the table.

```
//example
[1,2,3,4] -> "1,2,3,4"
```

Here is the code

```
public function update($id_service)
{
    $data = array(
        'charges_order' => implode(",", $_POST['charges_order'])
    );
    // echo '<pre>', print_r($data);
    $this->M_report->update($id_service, $data);
    redirect('backend/report');
}
```

When you are retrieving, you can reverse the process

```
public function get_orders($id_service)
{
    $this->db->select('charges_order');
    $this->db->where('id_service', $id_service);
    $result = $this->db->get('service')->result_array();
    return explode(",", $result["charges_order"]); //returns an array
}
```