# insert array type checkbox and text with php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to insert array data from checkbox and input text with php codeigniter

this is my view

```
 <?php foreach ($data_ikan as $row) { ?>
<tr>
 <td>
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ikan[]" value="<?php echo $row['nama_ikan']; ?>" id="checkbox<?php echo $row['id_data_ikan']; ?>">
<label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox<?php echo $row['id_data_ikan']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['nama_ikan']; ?>
</label>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="produksi[]" class="form-control form-input-sm my-1" id="produksi<?php echo $row['id_data_ikan'] ?>" placeholder="Kg" disabled>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Can help me?

Thanks
Best Regrads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this :

```
<?php foreach ($data_ikan as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="form-check-input" onclick="return show('<?=$row['id_data_ikan']?>')" type="checkbox" name="ikan[]" value="<?=$row['id_data_ikan']?>" id="checkbox<?=$row['id_data_ikan']?>"><?=$row['nama_ikan']?>
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="produksi<?=$row['id_data_ikan']?>" class="form-control form-input-sm my-1" id="produksi<?=$row['id_data_ikan']?>" placeholder="Kg" disabled>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

add javascript function

```
<script>
function show(id) {
  if(document.getElementById('checkbox'+id).checked){
    document.getElementById("produksi"+id).disabled = false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("produksi"+id).disabled = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: mau masukan data checkbox sama form input text itu ke db mas, cuma ga tau logika insert nya karena bentuk array. jadi ketika checkbox diceklist, form input jadi not disable nah itu nampung hasil variable checkbox sama input text nya gimana ya mas?

Comment: Untuk javascriptnya kebetulan sudah saya buat mas. yang bingung cuma insert array ke databasenya. ini bentuk arraynya mas   ["ikan"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "aaa" [1]=> string(4) "gggg" } ["produksi"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(2) "15" }

Comment: coba ikuti link @Dum, permasalahanya cuman insert ke table kan, 1 id pesan banyak ikan dan jumlah produksi kan??

Comment: problem solved with array_map mas terimaka kasih :)

Answer (score 0):

For checkboxes

```
$checkboxes = $_POST["ikan[]"];
```

Then you can loop through it

```
foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox){
   //code
}
```

Comment: how about input type text?? i want insert both. Can it be foreach loop?

Comment: You can, did you try this for checkboxes ?

Comment: i want insert both checkbox and text, but i dont know for save that array and insert to database. i can insert it to database if the data just checkbox, but i need checkbox and input text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027567/12731030 this may help you.